# Does a CRM 2011 workflow in a WAIT STATE use system resources, specifically the async service?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We have some workflows waiting on approvals.  They show business process status = "Running".  I read a blog that says wait conditions use resources via the async service (didn't say what: memory? CPU?).

My question is, does a wait condition in a CRM 2011 workflow use resources, and if so, what kind (memory, CPU, or both), and is it significant.

This question is coming up because our async service is spiking up to using over 36 gigs of memory during the day (at some point, the server then crashes).

Comment: How many workflows do you have currently in a waiting state?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely it does.  Waiting workflows need to be used sparingly.  There are other ways to achieve the same result

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation to your answers. Possibly ways to achieve the same results? See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.